# Contact Form won't center within parent div

Tags: html, css, forms, center

I can't get my form to align in the center of a div. Driving me nuts!

I simply need this contact form to be centered, no matter the viewport size.
Right now it's off to left, but I can't figure it out. I've included a codePen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoLqPx)

And here's my [demo site](http://jasoncampbell.net46.net/mvp/demo.html)

The html for the form (and parent container) is below. Any feedback whatsoever is helpful! Thank you

```
<section id="contact" class="contact">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row mb50">

                    <div class="sec-title text-center mb50 wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-duration="500ms">
                        <h2>Get in touch</h2>
                        <div class="devider"><i class="fa fa-heart-o fa-lg"></i></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="sec-sub-title text-center wow rubberBand animated" data-wow-duration="1000ms">
                        <p>We welcome any question or comment you have - Expect a reply within 24 hours.</p>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Contact Form -->

                    <div id="contactbox">
                    <div id="contactholder">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-7 col-xs-12 wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                        <div class="contact-form">

                            <form action="#" id="contact-form">
                                <div class="input-group name-email">
                                    <div class="input-field">
                                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-field">
                                        <input type="email" name="email1" id="email1" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" class="form-control"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="submit" id="form-submit" class="pull-right" value="Send message">
                                </div>
                            </form>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- end contact form -->

              </div>
           </div>

        </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing Bootstrap grid layout with custom stuff. That's a recipe for a headache. Always use the grid for layout and apply your margins and padding *only to elements inside the innermost grid boxes* in your layout.

Removing your custom widths and using **[Bootstrap's grid offsets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting)** as nature intended takes care of things:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 ...
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPYVqj)**

I removed all this, which only fights with Bootstrap:

```
#contactbox{
    width:60%;
}
#contactholder{
    width:1000px;
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution and helpful explanation. Top notch! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The width on your contactBox is fine, here is how I like to do it:

Add a `col-centered` class

```
<div class="col-centered col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-7 col-xs-12 wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
  ...
</div>
```

And the styles:

```
.col-centered{
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  float: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the other post solved the issue but this seems to work too.